# First cell such that <condition>

Tags: macos, spreadsheet, iwork-numbers

Giving a range of cells say `A1:A4` how can I get the index `i` of the first cell such that `Ai` is greater than `x`. For the sake of the example, suppose cell `Ai` contains `10^i`.
I have:

```
MATCH(TRUE; A1:A4 >= 1000; 0)
```

I would like this to return 3. But instead I get the following error:

> MATCH couldn’t find the value “TRUE”.

I guess that means that the mapping from integers to boolean using `>` didn't work the way I though it would. Where is the problem here?

Here is how it looks, just in case I missed something I don't understand:

[image]

Comment: Also, is there a way to debug this, for example by displaying the intermediate result of `A1:A4 > 1000`?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand Numbers can't deal with vectorised operations of the form "collection > x" (whereas it seems like excel does and I've tested goole spreadsheet who does using the `ArrayFormula` keyword, ie. `ArrayFormula(MATCH(True, A1:A4 > 1000, 0))` works as expected).

On the other hand, for some strange reason they have implemented a similar feature in `COUNTIFS`, which can take a collection together with a condition (represented as a string … don't ask). This can be used to solve that particular problem:

```
1 + COUNTIFS(A1:A4; "<= 1000")
```

This counts the number of cells that do not match the original condition, and takes the index of the next cell.